# Sliders in fragment are not show when app run in android

Tags: android

The slider works but is displayed when I click on its BottomNavigationView!
i want to show after running the application without any click! in start fragment!

startFragment codes:

```
public class StartFragment extends Fragment {

private List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
private Activity activity;
private List<String> sliderImages = new ArrayList<>();


private SliderView sliderView;
private RecyclerView homeRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter productAdapter;


public StartFragment(Activity activity, List<Users> users, List<Product> products, List<String> sliderImages) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.products = products;
    this.users = users;
    this.sliderImages = sliderImages;
}




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_start , container ,false);
    init(rootView);
    return rootView;}


private void init(ViewGroup rootView) {
    bindView(rootView);
    fillSliderData();
    getProducts();



}




private void bindView(ViewGroup rootView) {
    sliderView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    homeRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView);
    manager = new GridLayoutManager(activity,1);
    homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
}



private void fillSliderData(){

    final StartSliderAdapter startSliderAdapter = new StartSliderAdapter(activity , sliderImages);
    sliderView.setSliderAdapter(startSliderAdapter);
    sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM);
    sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.DEPTHTRANSFORMATION);
    sliderView.startAutoCycle();

}

private void getProducts(){

    productAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(activity,products,activity , users);
    homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

}
```

}

users, product and SliderImages getting from database with Volly!

slider adapter codes:

```
public class StartSliderAdapter extends  SliderViewAdapter<StartSliderAdapter.myHolder>{



List<String> images ;
private Context context;

public StartSliderAdapter(Context context , List<String> images){
    this.images = images;
    this.context = context;
}





@Override
public myHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.slider_item , parent , false);

    StartSliderAdapter.myHolder holder = new StartSliderAdapter.myHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(images.get(position) , Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(i);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public class myHolder extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView imageView;

    public myHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        imageView =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.startSliderImages);
    }


}
```

}

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7xTf.jpg)

[after click again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Ukv.jpg)

Can you tell me my mistake and guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use OnViewCreated instead of private void init(ViewGroup rootView)

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { {
        bindView(rootView);
        fillSliderData();
        getProducts();
    }
```